# Ошибка при установке Google Cloud SDK

Tags: sdk, облако, google-cloud

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь установить Google Cloud SDK, но при установке компонент все крашится. Выдает следующие логи:

```
Output folder: C:\cloudgoogle
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\cloudgoogle\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display_taps
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_printer_base
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_projector
    from apitools.base.py import encoding
    from apitools.base.py.credentials_lib import *
    import oauth2client.client
    from oauth2client import crypt
    from oauth2client import _openssl_crypt
    from OpenSSL import crypto
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
    from cryptography import x509
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
    from asn1crypto.keys import PublicKeyInfo
    from ._elliptic_curve import (
    from ._int import inverse_mod
    from ._perf._big_num_ctypes import libcrypto
    libcrypto_path = find_library('crypto')
    fname = os.path.join(directory, name)
    result_path = result_path + p_path
This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
    C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.
If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 8, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 17, in <module>
    import oauth2client.contrib.gce as gce
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\contrib\gce.py", line 25, in <module>
    from oauth2client import client
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\client.py", line 51, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\crypt.py", line 45, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _openssl_crypt
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\oauth2client\_openssl_crypt.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from asn1crypto.keys import PublicKeyInfo
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\keys.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ._elliptic_curve import (
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_elliptic_curve.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._int import inverse_mod
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_int.py", line 56, in <module>
    from ._perf._big_num_ctypes import libcrypto
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_perf\_big_num_ctypes.py", line 31, in <module>
    libcrypto_path = find_library('crypto')
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\ctypes\util.py", line 53, in find_library
    fname = os.path.join(directory, name)
  File "C:\cloudgoogle\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to install.
```

Из логов видно, что что-то не так с кодировкой. устанавливаю в папку C:/cloud т.е. русских символов нет. Где-то прочитал о том, что нужно регион поменять->поставил Японию)),но и это не помогло. Можете посоветовать что-нибудь?
в разделе Issues у гугла тоже был, но и там ответа не нашел.
Спасибо.
P.S. заметил, что что-то не так с Phyton, но что именно понять не могу.

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема исчезает, если сначала установить требуемую версию питона (2.7)**, а затем устанавливать Google Cloud SDK. Но, естественно, галочку напротив установки связанного питона в предзагрузочном диалоге с загрузчиком SDK снимите. Также я добавил в переменные среды в раздел системных переменных переменную с именем CLOUDSDK_PYTHON, её значение - полное имя исполняемого файла предустановленного питона (у меня это C:\Python27\python.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло переименовывание папки пользователя в латиницу, а также указанием зависимостей: CLOUDSDK_PYTHON - C:\Python27\python.exe

А также удаление всех зависимостей, при предыдущих попытка установить SDK

Answer (score -1):

Не правильно я все делал))
Идёте [сюда](https://console.cloud.google.com), регистрируетесь. Там выбираете API, который вам нужен, получаете Credentials, у Google json файлом скачивается и добавляется в проект(но советую ABBYY OCR SDK т.к. больше файлов можно обрабатоть(бесплатно)).